# PHP Internal Server Error with $statement->execute

Tags: php, error-handling, mysqli, prepared-statement, internal-server-error

So I'm using PHP with Mysqli and I'm trying to run a very basic prepared Statement:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT field FROM blubb WHERE id=? AND username=? LIMIT 1");

while($doingStuff){
  // Do Stuff
  $stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $username);
  $stmt->execute();
  // Do Stuff
}
```

But I get an Internal Server Error when I try to run the execute.

I already set

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

in my Script, thinking I might get an Error Message to know whats wrong, but it's still an Internal Server Error.

I also tried

```
$stmt->execute() or die("error msg");
```

but still the same Error, also theres nothing in the Server Error Logs.
What I also tried was explicitly casting the $id to int, didn't help.

How can I debug this and find the Error? I can't seem to get a proper Error Message out of my Script and I have no clue what could be wrong, since other prepared Statemens I use run fine.

edit: Ok I just found the source of the Problem, I was trying to do this

```
while($doStuff){
  method($stmt1, $stmt2)
}
method($stmt1, $stmt2){
  // handle $stmt1
  // stuff
  // handle $stmt2
}
```

Which is not possible according to this Article 
http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/889/php-mysqli-and-multiple-prepared-statements/

I fixed the Error by simply changing

```
while($doingStuff){
  // Do Stuff
  $stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $username);
  $stmt->execute();
  // Do Stuff
}
```

to

```
while($doingStuff){
  // Do Stuff
  $stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $username);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  // Do Stuff
}
```

on the first Statement.

But I'd still like to know how I can get the actual Error instead of Internal Server Error, since I'm using shared hosting I can't change the php.ini

Comment: Did you do `var_dump($stmt)` to make sure it's not `false` or something?

Comment: What if you wrap the ? sign in `username=?` with single quotes?

Comment: If logging is enabled, there has to be something in the server log, are you sure you checked the right log?

Comment: Have you tried setting [`display_startup_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors) on? Depending on your settings, you might be able to use `ini_set("display_startup_errors", "on")`. Otherwise, edit your php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors), [log_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) and [error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) directives on the PHP configuration, not from the script: either php.ini or, if allowed and supported, .htaccess.